# tab expanding using transform and cubic bezier

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, webkit, css-transforms

Trying to write better questions, so here goes.

I have 5 tabs that work, enlarging on hover. How do I get rid of the space between the tabs, before hover, so the tabs are next to each other?

I've tried everything I know and researched it but I still can't figure it out.

The tabs are the color boxes over the carousel http://digidonkey.net/dev/

Here is my css:

```
.nav.nav-justified > li > a > img { 
    max-width: 100%; 
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9,.9);
            transform: scale(.9,.9);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
            transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
.nav.nav-justified > li.active > a > img,
.nav.nav-justified > li:hover > a > img,
.nav.nav-justified > li:focus > a > img { 
     opacity: 1; 
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
            transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
.tab-pane .tab-inner { padding: 30px 0 20px; }
.tab-li-a {padding:0 !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked

```
.nav.nav-justified > li > a > img { 
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.nav.nav-justified > li.active > a > img,
.nav.nav-justified > li:hover > a > img,
.nav.nav-justified > li:focus > a > img { 
    transform: scale(1.1);
    margin-right:31px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Following changes, It will give required output.

```
.nav.nav-justified > li > a > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    /* -webkit-transform: scale(.9,.9); */
    /* transform: scale(.9,.9); */
    /* -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275); */
    /* transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275); */
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rukhasana,

I added your code as is, to my style sheet but that doesn't seem to work. It is targeting the tab images, but it is not making the necessary  changes, getting rid of the space between tab images when the tabs are in the down state, unless I missed something.

Is there anything else you think might work?